# How do you get every value for an attribute that all the elements contain from a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my first question and i hope it makes sense because i am quite a rookie at javascript/jquery.

So, i have a varying amount of elements with the custom attribute `data-value=<?php echo $value ?>`

Once the page has loaded I have some javascript `$('[data-value]')` to select all the elements on the page with the attribute 'data-value'. This returns an array with all the relevant elements. Then i tried getting the values with `$('[data-value]').data('value')`. Now, while this is returning the right result, it's only returning it for the first element it comes across. I tried iterating through the code with `$('[data-value]')[num].data('value')` where 'num' is between zero and the array length. This, sadly, didn't work.

So is there any way to grab all the values of a particular attribute that all the selected elements have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method to iterate through your elements.

```
$('[data-value]').each(function() {
    console.log( $(this).data('value');
}
```

You can also use the for loop as you have tried, with a simple modification.
When you do `$('[data-value]')[num]`, you actually get the native element, and not a jQuery object, so `.data()` is no longer available. To fix this, you can re-wrap the element in a jQuery object. `$( $('[data-value]')[num] ).data('value')`

Comment: Thanks, this worked well for me and also the extra infomation about having to rewrap the native element was very helpful

Answer (score 3):

To get the values of all the selected elements, you need to loop through the list and pick the value of those, like this:

```
var values = $("[data-value]").map(function(i, el) {
  return el.data('value');
});

console.log(values);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
$('[data-value]').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).data('value'));
});
```